How to read IActionResult from Stream?
I have a method in some micro service in C#:
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(FileStreamResult), StatusCodes.Status200OK, "application/pdf")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(long id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var result = await service.RenderIfExists(id, cancellationToken);

    if (result is null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
 
    Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");

    return File(fileContents: result,contentType: "application/pdf",fileDownloadName: $"lalala");
}

When I invoke this endpoint from Swagger, I can download the returned file.
I have to just invoke this endpoint from another micro service with GetStreamAsync and return the result as is. But I don't understand how. I also have to do this using stream to avoid saving result in LOH.
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(long id, CancellationToken token)
{
    const string @base = "lalala";
    var url = $"lalala";
    var path = @base + url;
    var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(path, token);
    // ???
}


Results.Stream(Stream, ...) ?

@MarcGravell, thank you a lot!! That works almost like I need. Now I recieve result with "Response headers:
content-type: application/octet-stream". How can I get it as when I invoke first endpoint:
Response headers
content-disposition: attachment; filename="___ _______ _ ________ _ 1"; filename*=UTF-8''%D0%90%D0%BA%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%E2%84%96%201
content-length: 72593
content-type: application/pdf

In other words, I lose contentType and fileDownloadName

I've tried "return Results.Stream(stream, contentType: "application/pdf", fileDownloadName: "lalala");", but I received "Unrecognized response type; displaying content as text." :(

I've solved the problem! I've wrote "Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");"
